# Does anyone know where to find a good source of Linux update repositories?

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates

Whenever I attempt to update using apt-get update my Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine runs into these errors

```
W: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
```

I'm using a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 for practice for a competition and I run into the same error in competition.

Comment: You are behind some proxy that doesn't allow to get to the repos.

Answer (score 1):

Those repositories have been tested and work AOK. Your internet connection is censored  by a proxy server which does not allow you access to them. Please consult your IT department or whoever provides your Internet feed.